# Calling method in parent class from subclass methods in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I've used `super` to initialize parent class but I cannot see any way of calling parent class from subclass methods.

I know PHP and other languages do have this feature but cannot find a good way to do this in Ruby.

What would one do in this situation?

Answer (score 107, accepted):

If the method is the same name, i.e. you're overriding a method you can simply use `super`.  Otherwise you can use an `alias_method` or a binding.

```
class Parent
  def method
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  alias_method :parent_method, :method
  def method
    super
  end

  def other_method
    parent_method
    #OR
    Parent.instance_method(:method).bind(self).call
  end
end
```

Comment: This doesn't work. `Child.new.other_method` returns `NoMethodError: super: no superclass method 'other_method' for #<Child:0x007fca161a9400>`. The call to `super.method()` will only call `method` on whatever gets returned from the call to `super` (which, in this case, doesn't exist). `super` is not a reference to an instance's `superclass`.

Comment: Also calling `super` will call super with exact arguments that was passed to the child method. If you want to specify specify arguments you can by calling super with them:  EG: `def child(a, b); super; end` vs `def child(a, b); super(somevar); end`

Answer (score 22):

The [`super` keyword](http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_classes.html#S1) calls a method of the same name in the super class:

```ruby
class Foo
  def foo
    "#{self.class}#foo"
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  def foo
    "Super says: #{super}"
  end
end

Foo.new.foo # => "Foo#foo"
Bar.new.foo # => "Super says: Bar#foo"
```

Answer (score 18):

The `super` keyword in Ruby actually calls a method of the same name in the parent class. ([source](http://archive.railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?pid=25310#p25310))

```
class Foo
  def foo
    # Do something
  end
end

class Bar < Foo
  def foo
    super # Calls foo() method in parent class
  end
end
```

Comment: Putting an example in Java is not the best idea if the requester explicitly mentions PHP as other language he knows...

Comment: this answer was helpful to me, and he says he knows PHP AND other languages have this feature (not that he only knows PHP).

Answer (score 18):

Others have said it already well. Just one additional note of caution:

The syntax `super.foo` to call method `foo` in the super class is **not supported**. Rather it will call the `super`-method and on the returned result, try to call `foo`.

```
  class A
    def a
      "A::a"
    end
  end

  class B < A
    def a
      "B::a is calling #{super.a}" # -> undefined method `a` for StringClass 
    end
  end
```

Comment: This is an important distinction people should be aware of, so thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 8):

```
class Parent
  def self.parent_method
    "#{self} called parent method"
  end

  def parent_method
    "#{self} called parent method"
  end
end

class Child < Parent

  def parent_method
    # call parent_method as
    Parent.parent_method                # self.parent_method gets invoked
    # call parent_method as
    self.class.superclass.parent_method # self.parent_method gets invoked
    super                               # parent_method gets invoked 
    "#{self} called parent method"      # returns "#<Child:0x00556c435773f8> called parent method"
  end

end

Child.new.parent_method  #This will produce following output
Parent called parent method
Parent called parent method
#<Child:0x00556c435773f8> called parent method
#=> "#<Child:0x00556c435773f8> called parent method"
```

`self.class.superclass == Parent #=> true`

`Parent.parent_method` and `self.class.superclass` will call `self.parent_method`(class method) of `Parent` while
`super` calls the `parent_method`(instance method) of `Parent`.

Answer (score 6):

As of Ruby 2.2, `super_method` can also be used to call super of method a from method b.

```
method(:a).super_method.call
```

Comment: This is much cleaner than the `alias_method` alternative. Thanks for sharing!