# Usage of class_attribute when calling from non overloaded method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

See the code below you will understand what I am trying to achieve:

```
class Parent
  class_attribute :name
  def self.fun
    puts name
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  self.name = "my name"
  def self.other_func
    self.superclass.fun
    # or Parent.fun
  end
end

Child.other_func
```

I don't get any output. Had the name of other_func been fun it would have printed "my name" on the rails console. How do I achieve the same thing when calling from other_func ?

**EDIT** In my Child class there is already a method

```
def self.fun
```

which is doing some extra work on top of calling `Parent.fun`. So, calling directly 'fun' from 'other_func' is not an option for me.

Comment: Did you check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448831/calling-method-in-parent-class-from-subclass-methods-in-ruby. Call just `fun`

Comment: Why is calling `super` from the ChildClass not an option? Maybe you are overcomplicating things. Calling super does not prevent you from doing other things in your function.

Comment: Because it modifies the value returned by Parent class method, which I don't want. That code was already written by somebody else

Answer (score 3):

Sure you get `nil` as an output, although your `Parent.fun` is successfully called.

The thing is `class_attribute` does not work as you expect it to work. This would shed a light on the issue:

```
class Parent
  class_attribute :name
  self.name = :super
  def self.fun
    puts "super: #{self.name}"
  end
end

class Child < Parent
  self.name = :child
  def self.fun
    puts 'child'
  end 
  def self.other_fun
    Parent.fun
  end
end

Child.other_fun
#⇒ super: super
```

That said, class attributes *are not derived*.

Comment: so we must have default attribute(in parent class) in these cases ? what if we want to call the parent class method form multiple classes having the same kind of issue with each class having it's own attribute? I know we can send name as an argument to parent class' method. But don't we have any other option than that ?

Comment: I am not sure I follow. There are reasons `class_attribute` method is **not exist** in Ruby. Classes do not share attributes, that is not how inheritance works.

Comment: all Child classes have their own attribute which they are not supposed to share among themselves